# RestKit Creates New Object After Upload Instead Of Updating Existing One

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping, restkit

I am using `RestKit` to upload an Image to my backend. Unfortunately after a successful upload the response is not being mapped to the object I used in the request.

```
let imageFile = RKManagedObjectStore.defaultStore().mainQueueManagedObjectContext.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ImageFile") as ImageFile
let request = RKObjectManager.sharedManager().multipartFormRequestWithObject(imageFile, method: .POST, path: "/api/imageFile/", parameters:nil) { (formData) -> Void in
        formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageFileEntity.data, name: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }

    let operation = RKObjectManager.sharedManager().managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest(request, managedObjectContext: RKManagedObjectStore.defaultStore().mainQueueManagedObjectContext, success: { (operation, result) -> Void in
        println("result: \(result)")
        println("imageFileID: \(imageFile.imageFileID)")

        }) { (operation, error) -> Void in

    }
    RKObjectManager.sharedManager().enqueueObjectRequestOperation(operation)
```

If I print out my `imageFile` object after the operation was successful it seems that no mapping was applied to it:

```
<ImageFile: 0x7fe079821f20> (entity: ImageFile; id: 0x7fe079821fc0 <x-coredata:///ImageFile/tC23CCB0E-7CD8-4722-B075-3845B32EF4194> ; data: <fault>)
```

However if I print the result it shows another `ImageFile` object that indeed contains the mappings.

```
"<null>" = "<ImageFile: 0x7ff2f412aaf0> (entity: ImageFile; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://53E33858-A003-4331-A28D-56EC7C323AE1/ImageFile/p5> ; data: {\n imageFileID = 25;\n})";
```

I think since I am using `RKObjectManager` the mapping should be applied to the object I used in the request instead of a new one being created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by setting the `targetObject` property of `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` to `imageFile`

```
operation.targetObject = imageFile
```